# Etymology of the noun-form of gamy / gamey

Tags: meaning, etymology

I was watching Futurama and there was a scene where Fry tasted a steak and said it tasted **gamy** (or *gamey*). Now I've looked up on several dictionaries and they all state that in the context of meat it describes a strong flavor or odor of **game**. However when I lookup the aforementioned word game and it's plethora of definitions there isn't a single definition that relates to any form of meat or even food for that matter. What does this game exactly mean?

Comment: Game is hunting prey, typically birds. But in Africa lions my bad Cecil was killed by a trophy hunter.

Comment: Here is a link to wikipedia's description of game in terms of hunting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_(hunting)

Comment: You mean "a steak".

Comment: Could you please specify which dictionaries you consulted and what the concrete senses that seemed mismatched were there? It seems unlikely that this would not have been covered in them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This probably goes without saying, but it hasn't been directly addressed by any of the existing answers.

The word **game**, which originally and primarily means roughly *a form of amusement*, evolved to mean meat by way of ***hunting*** as a form of amusement.

*OED* definition **15** walks the line between the original meaning and the meaning referring to hunted meat.

> **15.** Originally: †entertainment derived from the chase *(obs.)*. In later use: the sport of hunting and shooting (or otherwise catching or killing) animals, birds, etc., as a countryside pursuit.

From there it took on the meaning referred to here, which developed the adjectival form **gamey**.

> The flesh of a game animal or game bird used as food.

This form is first attested in **1658.**

Answer (score 5):

Gamy is an alternative spellings of ***[gamey](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gamey) :***

> also gamy, 1844....***Meaning "tasting or smelling strongly" is from 1863.***

From [game](https://www.etymonline.com/word/game):

> "the sport of hunting, fishing, hawking, or fowling" (c. 1300), thus "wild animals caught for sport" (c. 1300).

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 3):

Game in this context means:

> a. Wild animals hunted for food or sport.
>
> b. The flesh of these animals, eaten as food.

Source https://www.thefreedictionary.com/game (Look at the #9 definition)